# Python sorting in order ouput file

Tags: python, sorting, output

```
nums = range(201,202)
with open('Orig.txt', 'r') as fin:
     with open('out.txt', 'w') as fout:
         for line in fin.readlines():
             line = line.split()

             for i in range(0, len(nums),):
                 line[1] = int(line[1]) + 1
                  #line.append(str(line[1] + 1))
                 line = [str(e) for e in line] 
                 print(line)
                 fout.write(' '.join(line) + '\n')
```

Input file

```
xxx1A   201 18  0   1   0   0   1
xxx2A   201 20  0   1   0   0   1
```

Currently the output looks like this

```
1A  201 18  0   1   0   0   1
1A  202 18  0   1   0   0   1
2A  201 20  0   1   0   0   1
2A  202 20  0   1   0   0   1
```

Whereas I would like it sorted by the third row / or second row i.e.

```
1A  201 18  0   1   0   0   1
2A  201 20  0   1   0   0   1
1A  202 18  0   1   0   0   1
2A  202 20  0   1   0   0   1
```

Any sugestions i've tried sort / reverse etc

Comment: You should open the first file, read it, then sort it as you want and then write in the output file. Not opening both of them and trying to write something all the time. Won't work.

Comment: Ok clear but could be done as part of the write to the file ?

Comment: No, you should read, sort than write. Separate your logic first, as you need to learn algorithms first. You need to learn how to walk before running a marathon.

Answer (score 0):

You can use pandas:

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv('temp.txt', sep=" ", header=None) #load to pandas
data = data.sort_values(2) #number of column, which you need sort
data.to_csv('new_temp.txt', header=None, index=False, sep=' ') # write to new txt, remember that numerate from 0
```

Comment: Thanks that works. Is there a way to further sort it via column 1 and column 2 i.e. it produces 1A  201 20  0   1   0   0   1
2A  201 22  0   1   0   0   1 1A  201 18  0   1   0   0   1
2A  201 21  0   1   0   0   1 so the third column is also sorted ?

Comment: Year, you need write inside `data.sort_values(2)` instead 2 next list with compilation columns `data.sort_values([1,2])`

Comment: data = data.sort_values(by= [1,2]) this works a treat

Comment: Good) glad helped. If all good you can tick my decision right